# Angular How can i redefine global body styles in other module?

Tags: angular, sass

I have an index.scss in app module. There are styles

```
html,
body {
        max-width: 1400px;
        margin: auto;
}
```

Also i have other module, module2, i don't need styles above here, how can i "turn-off" this?
I tried redeclare this styles in main component in module2, but it doesn't help:

```
max-width: unset !important;
margin: 0 !important;
```

Comment: You can try [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation) options but this solution is on component level and not on module level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your css selectors in second module main component style file.
Then Set ViewEncapsulation to None in the main component in second module